# Заменить отрицательные элементы в знакочередующейся последовательности на минимальный положительный элемент этой з.ч. последовательности

Tags: c++, массивы

Например, в массиве `{3 5 -4 6 -2 7 9 10 -11 15 13}` последовательность `{ 5 -4 6 -2 7}` - знакочередующаяся. Нужно заменить `-4` и `-2` на `5` (минимальное значение положительного элемента в этой знакочередующейся последовательности)
Вывод: `3 5 5 6 5 7 9 10 -11 15 13`

У меня получается совсем другой вывод, а именно: `{3 5 5 6 6 7 9 10 10 15 13}`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код.

```
    cout << "n: ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    int* array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) 
            min = array[i];
        if ((array[i] > 0) && (array[i + 1] < 0)) 
            array[i + 1] = min;
        cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере получается две таких последовательности:

1. {5 -4 6 -2 7};
2. {10 -11 15};

В вашем коде, если минимальное положительное число будет в середине или конце последовательности, значение не будет взято.

`if ((array[i] > 0) && (array[i + 1] < 0))`  - выход за предел массива при `i = n - 1`.

В конце программы нет удаления динамического массива - оператор `delete [] _имя указателя_`.

Написал код, протестировал, вроде работает как поставлена задача.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    /*cout << "Enter n: ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    int* arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }*/

    const int n = 11;

    int arr[n] = { 3, 5, -4, 6, -2, 1, 9, 15, -11, 10, 13 };

    int min;

    cout << "Source array :\t\t";
    for (auto &ind : arr) {
        cout << ind << "   ";       
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int k = 0;
        if (((arr[i] >= 0) && (arr[i + 1] < 0) && i != n - 1) || ((arr[i] < 0) && (arr[i + 1] >= 0) && i != n - 1)) {
            j = i;          
            if (arr[i] > 0) {
                min = arr[i];               
            }
            else {
                min = arr[i + 1];
            }
            while (((arr[j] >= 0) && (arr[j + 1] < 0) && j < n) || ((arr[j] < 0) && (arr[j + 1] >= 0) && j < n)) {
                if (arr[j] >= 0 && arr[j] < min) {
                    min = arr[j];
                }
                ++k;
                ++j;
            }
            if (arr[j] >= 0 && arr[j] < min) {
                min = arr[j];
            }           

            for (int t = i; t < i + k; ++t) {
                if (arr[t] < 0) {
                    arr[t] = min;
                }
            }
            i += k;
        }
    }

    cout << "Modified array :\t";
    for (auto &ind : arr)
    {
        cout << ind << "   ";   
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //delete[] arr;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Source array :          3   5   -4   6   -2   1   9   15   -11   10   13

Modified array :        3   5   1   6   1   1   9   15   10   10   13

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```